# SonarQube - Import existing checkstyle xml-file into SonarQube fails

Tags: xml, import, sonarqube, checkstyle, rules

I have installed SonarQube 5.1.2 and Checkstyle Plugin 2.3.

Problem: How can I import a Checkstyle XML configuration file? When I try to export a pre-installed FindBugs or Checkstyle rules configuration into an XML file, the export works. Then I try to import the same rules with other name and it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="authorFormat" value="^.../[^,]+(,\s.../[^,]+)*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocStyle"/>
    <module name="ConstantName"/>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName"/>
    <module name="MethodName"/>
    <module name="PackageName"/>
    <module name="ParameterName"/>
    <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
    <module name="TypeName"/>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="IllegalImport"/>
    <module name="RedundantImport"/>
    <module name="UnusedImports"/>
    <module name="MethodLength"/>
    <module name="ParameterNumber"/>
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="max" value="180"/>
      <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter"/>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
    <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
    <module name="ParenPad"/>
    <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,LITERAL_ASSERT,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND,WILDCARD_TYPE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF,ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly"/>
    <module name="NeedBraces"/>
    <module name="RightCurly"/>
    <module name="AvoidInlineConditionals"/>
    <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
    <module name="HiddenField">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>
    <module name="DesignForExtension">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FinalClass"/>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor"/>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <property name="packageAllowed" value="true"/>
      <property name="protectedAllowed" value="true"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TodoComment"/>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
    <module name="MissingOverride"/>
  </module>
  <module name="JavadocPackage">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"/>
  <module name="Translation"/>
  <module name="FileLength"/>
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="^\s*@[A-Za-z]+(\([^\)]*\))?\s+[^\(].+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Do not use inline annotations"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="\([^)]*@[^\s]+\s\s+.*\)"/>
    <property name="message" value="Use single space after inline annotation"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

I have already tried to export an existing pre-installed rule-set and tried to import it back with other name. But that causes the same failure.

Is this also a bug?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "with other name".

Comment: For testing the export and import function of sonarqube for bugs, I just export the default ruleset of Java Sonar way (default ruleset) into a xml file. The same file I try to import in the same sonar enviroment. And it doesn't work. This is terrible.

The reason for this test is, that I cannot import my file which I have exported from exlipse checkstyle plugin (version 5.7.0)

With 'other name' I mean, when you try to import the same ruleset which already excist, then you have to give it a new name. ('Sonar way' becomes for example 'Sonar way 2')

Many thanks for all the corrections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You speak of importing a profile, but show what appears to be a tool-specific XML file, not one related to a SonarQube quality profile.

There are two types of things you can export and import:

1. SonarQube Quality Profiles - these can be imported to a SonarQube server to *create* the profile named in the file. If a profile of that name already exists, you will indeed get an error.
2. Tool-specific rule sets - for certain languages, these can be exported from a profile and imported when a new profile is *created*

Neither type of import functionality can be used to *update* an existing profile.

The functionality used to exist to import Checkstyle, PMD, and FindBugs rule sets at the creation of a Java profile, but since the SonarQube Java plugin has replaced a majority of rules from each of those plugins, that functionality has been removed.

Comment: 1. This file which I try to import is a file that is generated by the eclipse checkstyle plugin. It generates an xml file. This shall be possible to import it in sonarqube checkstyle plugin. It makes no sens that I can export it but not import it.

2. I think I find a solution.
Look this link: http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/checkstyle.html

Comment: 1. It does make sense because you're talking apples (Eclipse plugin) and oranges (SonarQube plugin).

2. That report shows which Checkstyle rules have been replaced by new rules in the Java plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now it works for me. But is the goal to replace all checkstyle rules by Sonar rules? And do you have something like SonarLint? SonarLint1.0 doesn't support remote connection to the SonarQube Server. I read that the SonarLint Version 2.0 this shall do.

Comment: The goal is to replace all *valuable* Checkstyle rules. That's why the report you found marks some of the rules "rejected". I don't understand what you're asking about SonarLint; it's a SonarSource product, so yes, we have SonarLint. :)

Comment: The point is, if you use checkstyle in eclipse, the just-in-time analyze works pretty well. With Sonarqube we always have to press Analyze. This is not cool. And SonarLint exists at that moment just as Version 1.0. I try it out and i had to notice that there is no posibility to connect to the Sonarqube server. We need a just in time analyzer without pressing any key. :-)